# Timestamp can not enter into Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, timestamp

This time I had a problem in Mysql with message error :

```
2016-10-11 16:16:15
object(DateTime)#1 (3) { ["date"]=> string(26) "2016-10-11 16:16:15.000000" ["timezone_type"]=> int(3) ["timezone"]=> string(12) "Asia/Jakarta" }
```

> Catchable fatal error: Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string in /opt/lampp/htdocs/bus/index.php on line 16

I want the data to $d can get into mysql and the results of the timestamp can get into mysql without error.

And this is source code try:

```
$d = new DateTime('2016-10-11T09:16:15.000Z');$d->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Asia/Jakarta'));
echo $d->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')."<br />"; // 2016-10-06T09:50:54.000000
var_dump($d);


$host="localhost";
$user="root";
$pass="";
$db="baru";

/*Koneksi database*/
 $spot = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass) or die ("Koneksi gagal");
 mysql_select_db($db, $spot) or die ("Koneksi gagal");

$sql = "INSERT INTO time (`timestamp`) values ( '$d' )"; 
mysql_query($sql);
```

with structure DB:

```
______ Name ________ Type _____________ Collation ______
1   id(Primary)     int(40)             
2   timestamp       varchar(30)     latin1_swedish_ci
```

Thanks.

Comment: Saving `timestamp` in a `varchar`?

Comment: `$d` is still an object, assign `$d->format` inside a variable then use it inside the query, and please, use `timestamp` datatype, not `varchar`, and its time to use PDO

Comment: Hi, I change the data type (Varchar) to (Timestamp), but still error. Is the Ghost could show the arrangement of code?

Comment: give datatype as  'timestamp' to timestamp field